# Search and copying nodes from one graph to another in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

Suppose  you have 3 graphs with where some data is shared among the graphs. Is there then a way programatically to do the following:

1. In graph 1 find a node
2. Search in graph 2 for that node (through property name)
3. If step 2 finds a match, then I would like to take all the nodes connected to the found node in graph 2 (including "nodes indirectly connected") and connect them to the node in graph 1.

Essentially I would like to search for a particular node in a graph, find all the nodes directly or indirectly connected to and copy the entire connection to my original node in graph 1.

Any hints on how to do this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Using Neo4j 1.9 and not too familar with Cypher queries and it is the community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all your 3 graphs in a single database it is simple.

do the query to find your node

```
START a=node.... MATCH ... WHERE ... RETURN a.prop as prop, ID(a) as id
```

assuming your nodes are indexed for the properties that are interesting for you, do an index lookup for that property

```
START a=node({id}), b=node:index(property={prop}) 
MATCH (b)-->(c) 
CREATE (c)-[:REL_TYPE]->(a)
```

Comment: Does CREATE (c) connect the nodes to your original node? Thanks for the code.